# Building iOS with Ionic 4 and cordova google plugins

Tags: firebase, cordova, cocoapods, cordova-plugins, ionic4

when i try to add ios as new platform to my working android ionic 4 app i get tons of these messages:

> [!] Found multiple specifications for `GoogleDataTransport
>   (3.2.0)`:
>   - /Users/haraldwiesinger/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/3.2.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json
>   - /Users/haraldwiesinger/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/3.2.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `GoogleUtilities (6.4.0)`:
>   - /Users/haraldwiesinger/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.4.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json
>   - /Users/haraldwiesinger/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.4.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json

after reading a long time in existing tickets from github in these cordova plugins.. i found out that it has something to do with incompatible versions of the google services and the pod files the plugins are using.

i am using `cordova-plugin-firebasex` and `cordova-plugin-googleplus`.

the solution for others was to run pod update and pod install in their ios folder.. but i cant create the platform cause of these errors.. so i cant run the commands there.

i also tried to update the version of plugin.xml:
`<pod name="GoogleUtilities" spec="~> 6.13.0"/>`
from both plugins to the same value, but the error still exists

anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

found workaround solution:

file: plugins/cordova-plugin-googleplus/plugin.xml

```
<podspec>
      <config>
        <source url="https://cdn.cocoapods.org/"/>
      </config>
      <pods use-frameworks="true">
        <pod name="GoogleSignIn" spec="~> 4.4.0"/>
        <pod name="GoogleUtilities" spec="~> 6.4.0"/>
      </pods>
    </podspec>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried already a lot of combinations with different versions, but it is still not working.. i also change the config source to the new cocoapods.org but still nothing :(